# Styling closedview dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image][Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/604gh5ou/)

**Problem:**
   Hi, Check my fiddle. I want to capitalize the selected value alone[closed view value]. I mean when i open my drop-down, all options should be in lowercase. But selected option is in upper case.

**Code**

```
  <select>
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
  </select>

$("select").change(function () {
               $(this).find("option").text(function (i, text) {
                     return $(this).is(":selected") ?  text.toUpperCase() : text.toLowerCase();
               });
            })
```

Is it possible? If so, any suggestions. If not, please tell me the reason.
See the attachment please. This is what i called closed view

Comment: Right now you have selected value in upper case. Do you want to make all values lower case when you open dropdown again?

Comment: Yes Regent. There are two values. One in option group and another is Selected value which is viewable when dropdown is closed. That closed view value alone should be in uppercase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite weird workaround (when dropdown list is closed, selected option is upper case; when dropdown list is opened, all options are lower case), but should work:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/604gh5ou/6/).

```
var wasSelected = false;

$("select").click(function()
{
    if (!wasSelected) //on dropdown open
    {
        $(this).find("option:selected").text(function(i, text)
        {
            return text.toLowerCase();
        });
    }
    else
    {
        wasSelected = false;
    }
});

$("select").change(function()
{
    $(this).find("option").text(function(i, text)
    {
        return $(this).is(":selected") ? text.toUpperCase() : text.toLowerCase();
    });
    wasSelected = true;
});

$("select").change(); //initial dropdown formatting
$("select").click(); //initial dropdown formatting
```

**Update**. Even more workarounds, but should fix the mentioned issues:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/604gh5ou/7/).

```
var wasSelected = false;
var wasClicked = false;

$("select").click(function()
{
    if (wasClicked)
    {
        onClose($(this));
    }
    else if (!wasSelected)
    {
        $(this).find("option:selected").text(function(i, text)
        {
            return text.toLowerCase();
        });
        wasClicked = true;
    }
    else
    {
        wasSelected = false;
    }
});

$("select").change(function()
{
    wasSelected = wasClicked;
    onClose($(this));
});

$("select").blur(function()
{
    onClose($(this));
});

function onClose(jElement)
{
    jElement.find("option").text(function(i, text)
    {
        return $(this).is(":selected") ? text.toUpperCase() : text.toLowerCase();
    });
    wasClicked = false;
}

$("select").change();
```

Comment: @user3801433 the same story is with closing `<select>` by clicking outside of it. If it is important, I can try to fix these issues.

Comment: Thanks Rogent :) I ll give a try later if i face issues, i ll inform you.

Comment: @user3801433 I have complicated code even more in **Update**, but now it should work in most cases.

Comment: @user3801433 you're welcome. The only problem I saw was not handling "enter" key. Maybe you will finally come up with more elegant solution...

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('option').each(function(i){
    if(!$(this).is(':selected'))
        $(this).text($(this).text().toLowerCase());
    });
```

Check your fiddle. I have added the above code. I this all what u wanted??

Check this fiddle [Dropdown case change](http://jsfiddle.net/604gh5ou/8/)

Comment: Please add your fiddle in your answer

Comment: It's same as my result. After selecting the value, open the dropdown again. All options must be in lowercase

Comment: No, It's not as my expectation

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see your code is working fine. If you are looking to have the pre-selected value in UPPER case when the page loads, then you need to call the code on jQuery dom ready

You may use the following code

```
$("select").change(function () {
  modifySelectBox();
})

jQuery(document).ready(function(){        
    modifySelectBox()
})

function modifySelectBox() {
     $("#myselbox").find("option").text(function (i, text) {
         return $(this).is(":selected") ?  text.toUpperCase() : text.toLowerCase();
     });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="myselbox">
    <option selected="selected">One</option>    
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
</select>
```